# How to start separate discussion over any item in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, list-item

Some of our users asked for a feature so they can start discussion or asking question over any item in specific place. It means that the Created By is not one of the people to participate in discussion.
So I made a "Create List item" workflow and when an Item creat in a list, at same time, item will create in Discussion board and i filtered the view by [Me] and  [RecipientList]
I think it is not logic and there is a better way, (even a plug in) but I could not fiend. If any one have experience or note regarding this issue I would appreciate.
Regards
Shadi

Comment: It sounds like a logical approach. Is there something specific that isn't working for you?

Comment: I think this is logical way that I can thought.

Comment: thank you both for answers. Actually it is working and I have no problem but it didn't sound fine for me, that each conversation start in another place. so I decided to ask and look for different ways!